# When is “得” pronounced “de” and when is it pronounced “dei”?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

I have noticed that there are two different pronunciations of 得： - Usually it's pronounced "de". - in some situations it's pronounced "dei" as in:

```
老百姓想自强
那就得学习点别人先进的东西。
```

When is “得” pronounced “de” and when is it pronounced “dei”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 得
  děi

Is a verb that means:

> need/must

Like:

> 我们得走了
>   We gotta go.

---

- 得
  de

Is an auxiliary partial that modifies or qualifies a verb.

Like:

> 说得好！
>   Well said!

Comment: Perhaps you may also point out 得de for the word 不得, which means "shall not". It's a formal word which often appears in legal texts.